# Moving apps in app library

Tags: iphone, ios

I have several star-finding apps on my phone.   The App library has some of them in the "Education" folder, and some in the "Information & Reading" folder.

How can I get them all in the same folder?   They do the same thing.

Comment: I believe you will find the "App Library" is curated by your iPhone and not adjustable. If you want to keep them together the way to do that is put them in a folder together manually, outside of the so-called App Library.

Comment: I was hoping to get rid of my manual folders where I put all of my star-finding apps.   They do the same thing!!!

Comment: Welcome to "*The Apple Way*" </sarcasm off> Apple often does this "for reasons." There are many blogs, online magazines and podcasts that discuss this endlessly. If you *must* be able to customize *everything* on your devices you and Apple may not get along. If you can shrug it off (as I have been doing since 1990 ish) and not sweat the things you can't change then you will be fine.

Answer (score 4):

The App Library cannot be edited, it is a comprehensive sorted-by-your phone list. You can create your own App Library (in a sense) by creating a set of folders on your regular home screen.